# How to link google domain with aws beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I purchased a domain on google. I am using aws beanstalk. I was able to create a sample application with beanstalk url. But I would like to host my website with custom google domain.
Aws Docs are very confusing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First half of this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY6hWgo5xx0&t=258s) explains how to link your go-daddy domain with aws beanstalk. Same things apply for google domain. Login to your google domain and follow instructions in the video. Once done, it takes around 30 minutes for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the process very confusing and not well documented. Hopefully the steps I followed will save others time:

1. Have an Elastic Beanstalk account with a functional domain (will look like: myappname-myenvname.myamazonregion.elasticbeanstalk.com)
2. In Route 53, create your hosted zone. This should generate NS & SOA record items. Do not change these values, but you can adjust the time to live (TTL). Setting this requires judgment balancing your budget, visitor numbers and how frequently the content is changing.
3. Still in Route 53, create an "A" (alias) record. I kept routing policy simple & no evaluation of target health (I can do this myself thanks aws). You will need to add the value that the alias is redirecting traffic to, which is your AWS Elastic Beanstalk domain (refer to step 1).
4. In Google Domains, you will be setup with Google's standard name servers by default. Of course if we want to link to aws, we will need to point instead to their name servers. Choose custom name servers (the option was buried for me).
5. In Google Domains, add every NS (name server) record that was generated by your Route 53 Hosted Zone (step 2). There should be 2 - 4 records here, each on a newline. Some people recommend ensuring that these end with a `.`, but I found aws & Google Domains ignored the value anyway. Hit save.
6. Congrats, that's it! Mine took overnight to propagate, yours might be different. Also note Route 53 will begin charging when Hosted Zones are live for an extended period, even on the free plan (for me it was AUD $0.50 per month).